# How to show direction arrow in x-aixs in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts for a simple scatter Chart. I have  draw arrow in hAxis, i would like to set the hAxis arrow left and right .

Like 
[image: reuied chart]

but currently my scatter chart look like

[image: current]

i want to add data flow direction arrow in x-axis label

Comment: use the same process you're using to add the images to add the arrows, pass x-axis min (-100) & max (100) values to `layout.getXLocation` and zero (0) to `layout.getYLocation`...

Comment: how we can add two x-axis title